# Rewriting Wordpress URL

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Whats the best way to add a url rewrite for wp-login.php to become /login and wp-login.php=action?register to become /register

I tried to add one but seems like i was getting server errors..

At the moment my .htaccess file looks like this. . -

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# END WordPress
#
AuthType Basic
AuthName "2"
AuthUserFile "/home/site/.htpasswds/public_html/passwd"
require valid-user
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on

# Redirect /wp-login.php to /login
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /wp-login\.php\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /login [R=301,L]

# Resolve /login to /wp-login.php
RewriteRule ^login/?$ /wp-login.php [NC,L]

# Pass any css/js requests directly
RewriteRule ^login/(.+)$ /$1 [NC,L]

# Redirect register action request to /register
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (&|\?)action=register(\s|&) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /register? [R=301,L]

# Resolve /register with /wp-login.php again
RewriteRule ^register/?$ /wp-login.php?action=register [QSA,NC,L]

# Pass any css/js requests directly
RewriteRule ^register/(.+)$ /$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Hi, that worked great it seems like the register and login button doesnt seem to anything it. Is there something you have to call in wordpress so it knows there is a rewrite happening before you click the buttons?

Comment: Try adding two more rules as above that make sure that rewriting the URL doesn't interfere with any css/js requests from the original php page.